# Trying to design a tableviewcell with material-design Chips

Tags: swift, xcode, material-design, cosmicmind

it is my first question in the forum, although I have been reading for quite a long time.

I am trying to design a tableviewcell with XCode 10 in swift for accessing to documents that are translated into many languages. So what I want is to show the text of the document title and below, a CHIP (material-design) with the flag icon and the capital letters of the language.

I have made a sketch to show that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQGWg.jpg (i can not post images yet)

I read the information in the webpage for the material design, specifically the section for CHIPS in iOS: https://material.io/develop/ios/components/chips/

But all the information is in Objective-C, not in swift, and I have no idea of what they explain.

I have also take a look at cosmicmind material framework because it says in the readme file that one of the features is CHIPS, however I havent been able to find the example for CHIPS in the samples section.

Hope you can help me to design the cell.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I have solved the problem myself by using a collectionview embedded in the tableviewcell.

Within the storyboard, in the tableviewcontroller, add a prototype cell, give the height that you want, add a label with the "document title" and add a collectionview.

Add a prototype cell to the collectionview, give it the size you want, add a background, the flag icon and the language capital letters and that's all.

Drag and drop the outlets of the collectionview and the tableview, and set the tableview as the delegate for the collectionview... and you are done.

To make it look like an Android chip you should round the corners by adding in the tableviewcell, at "cellforrowat":

cell.chipBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 20

And then it will look like in Android.

I leave a snapshot of the result:

[document list with different languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU6v9.png)